# Convert SQL query to pivot

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't seem able to get the logic to convert the following query to a pivot SQL. My table has 20 columns with roles on them, I'd like to convert those columns into rows so, when exported to Excel, I can filter on a single column since the values can be the same on the 20 columns. So far what I've done is convert the 20 columns into a single one and then split that single one into rows:

```
select      distinct TASKID,
          regexp_substr(t.roles,'[^|]+', 1, lines.column_value) as role
from        (
            select    TASKID,
                      TRIM(ROLE1) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE2) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE3) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE4) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE5) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE6) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE7) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE8) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE9) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE10) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE11) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE12) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE13) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE14) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE15) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE16) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE17) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE18) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE19) || '|' ||
                      TRIM(ROLE20) as roles
            from      menu_roles
            where     RLTYPE='58'
          ) t,
          TABLE(CAST(MULTISET(select LEVEL from dual connect by instr(t.roles, '|', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0) as sys.odciNumberList)) lines
where     regexp_substr(t.roles,'[^|]+', 1, lines.column_value) is not null
order by  regexp_substr(t.roles,'[^|]+', 1, lines.column_value)
```

I'd understand that using PIVOT would be more efficient vs concatenating and splitting a string.

Thank you!

Comment: How about using `UNION` instead? `select taskid, role1 from menu_roles where rltype='58' union select taskid, role2 from menu_roles where rltype='58' union ... `

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: What do you mean?

Comment: @ammoQ: Unfortunately, can't do that, can't use UNION

Comment: @Jaquio PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language. Your code is entirely SQL (and not PL/SQL).

Comment: Ah, thank you for that, @MT0 and @a_horse_with_no_name! I was under the impression I was using "quirks" that Microsoft SQL Server did not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT task_id,
       role
FROM   menu_roles
UNPIVOT ( role FOR role_number IN ( ROLE1, ROLE2, ROLE3, ROLE4 /*, ... */ ) );
```

Or, using `UNION ALL`:

```
          SELECT task_id, role1 AS role FROM menu_roles
UNION ALL SELECT task_id, role2 AS role FROM menu_roles
UNION ALL SELECT task_id, role3 AS role FROM menu_roles
UNION ALL SELECT task_id, role4 AS role FROM menu_roles
-- ...
```

Comment: Thank you, @MT0. UNPIVOT was what I was looking for indeed